# How to identify a date Word FormField?

Tags: c#, office-interop

I'm working on a C# application that loads a Word document and tries to extract all FormFields (or bookmarks).

Using the following line of code...

```
wd.FormFields.get_Item(ref index).Type
```

I have no problem identifying a checkbox which returns wdFieldFormCheckBox or a drop-down list which returns wdFieldFormDropDown. When it comes to date fields I simply get wdFieldFormTextInput. This makes it indistinguishable from a regular text input field which also returns wdFieldFormTextInput. I need to be able to tell whether the input field is a date & time field or a date field or simply a time field. Is it possible to identify a date field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You ask:

> Is it possible to identify a date field?

... and yes, it is. If you take a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdfieldtype%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for the `WdFieldType` enum (which is the type of the [`FormField.Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.formfield.type%28v=office.14%29.aspx) property you use in your sample) you will see that it can have values like `wdFieldTime` and `wdFieldDate` - so yes, it should definitely be possible to identify a such field.

Comment: Thanks for replying to my post. I had a look at the documentation, but I'm still not sure on how I can identify the date and time fields. Would you happen you have example code?